# Error handling when the OS runs out of memory to allocate in C

Tags: c, malloc, out-of-memory

I am performing a memory intensive task. I would like to add a warning message when the operating system runs out of memory to allocate. When I run the code below, the process gets killed and my `if statement` for when the pointer is equal to `NULL` does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ONEGB (1<<30)

int main() {
        int count=0;

        while(1) {
                int *p = malloc(ONEGB);
                if (p == NULL) {
                        printf("There is not much memory left after %d GB\n", count);
                        return 0;
                }
                memset(p,1,ONEGB);
                fprintf(stderr, "got %d GB\n", ++count);
        }
}
```

The output was

> ```
> ...
> got 25 GB
> got 26 GB
> got 27 GB
> Killed
> ```

Is there some other way to tell the user that there is no memory left before the OS kills the process? I am mostly interested in running this on linux servers only.

Comment: Interesting can you comment `memset(p,1,ONEGB);` and see?

Comment: If I comment out memset, it allocates 131TB before it stops and prints the error message.

Comment: That is any way wrong, I don't suppose you have that much memory, you have to have keep `memset`, I just wanted to see you get the error. may be OS is playing some role here, lets wait for any good amswers

Comment: Read about OOM Killer  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first